# (BOX2D | OPENGL) Issue Matching Coordinates From World To Screen

Tags: c++, opengl, box2d

Im trying to get the coordinates of the Box2D objects to fit with the coordinates of the objects on screen(these being displayed with textures). I'm already aware that box2D works in meters so i would have to find a conversion factor that works for my program(in this case i said 50 pixels is 2 meters).

So would first set the position and size of the box with this:

```
b2BodyDef def
def.postition.Set(0.02 * x,  y* 0.02)
def.SetAsBox(0.02 * w/2, 0.02* h/2)
```

And since im using openGL i would just make a texture and render it like you normally would but this time I'm tring to match the textures x and y to the x and y of its collision box in Box2D.

And when i run the program whenever i try to move my player texture off of the floor texture, it falls off before it reaches the end. This let me know for sure that my box2D bodies and my OpenGL textures were not sharing the same positions. but whatever i do to try and fix that nothing ever changes(ex: i tried changing the conversion factor to 1m = 20p instead of 50p, i tried not converting the coordinates at all then i got some really wired result that also didnt work, and a bunch of other stuff). The worst part is box2D did the SAME THING when i was using SDL 2, and i switched to OpenGL thinking that this wouldn't happen again.

images from the demo:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4anrJs1BRh1aVpOYXI3T3JlWWM/view?usp=drivesdk 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4anrJs1BRh1dVlTb0czMTE3RWc/view?usp=drivesdk

Code for the tile class(currently the only class in my projects that uses box2D)

```
void tile::load(bool square, std::string path)
{
    if(square)
    {
        glGenTextures(1, &texID);
        SDL_Surface *sur = IMG_Load(path.c_str());
        w = sur->w;
        h = sur->h;
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, sur->w, sur->h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sur->pixels);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, NULL );
    }
}

void tile::addRect(int x, int y, int wt, int ht, bool dyn)
{
    b2BodyDef def;
    //Convert the x and y into meters.
    def.position.Set(vars::P2M * x, vars::P2M * y);

    if(dyn)
    {
        def.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    }


    b = vars::world->CreateBody(&def);

    b2PolygonShape shape; 

    //Convert the width and height entered into meters
    shape.SetAsBox(vars::P2M * w/2,vars::P2M * h/2);

    float th = w * 0.02;
    float tw = h * 0.02;

    b2FixtureDef fix;
    fix.shape = &shape;
    fix.density = 1.0;

    b->CreateFixture(&fix);

    h = h;
    w = w;
}

void tile::Render()
{
    glLoadIdentity();

    b2Vec2 pos;
    pos = b->GetPosition();
    float x = pos.x;
    float y = pos.y;
    //Convert the x and y of the body to pixels.
    glTranslatef(x * vars::M2P, y * vars::M2P, 0);

    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);


    glBegin( GL_QUADS );
        glTexCoord2f(0.f, 0.f); glVertex2f(0.f, 0.f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.f, 0.f); glVertex2f(w, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1.f, 1.f); glVertex2f(w, h);
        glTexCoord2f(0.f, 1.f); glVertex2f(0, h);
    glEnd();

}

void tile::Update()
{
    b2Vec2 vel;
    vel = b->GetLinearVelocity();
    if(key[SDL_SCANCODE_D])
    {
        d_key = true;
    }
    else
    {
        d_key = false;
    }
    if(key[SDL_SCANCODE_A])
    {
        a_key = true;
    }
    else
    {
        a_key = false;
    }
    if(a_key)
    {
        //Move the box left 
        vel.x = -5;
    }
    if(d_key)
    {
        //Move the box right
        vel.x = 5;
    }
    b->SetLinearVelocity(vel);
}
```

If anyone has an solution for this, please post it because im out of options and i dont know what to do anymore. Thanks.

oh and btw, 
vars::M2P = 50 and vars::P2M = 1/vars::M2P(which in-turn is 0.02).

Comment: "*I'm already aware that box2D works in meters*" No, it works in whatever units you want it to work in. If you decide that 1 Box2D unit is an inch, millimeter, or mile, Box2D will not care.

Comment: In all the tutorials i followed they used meters, so i used that unit aswell :/